# $\left | \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n b_n z^{n} \right | \leq C \left | \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} b_n z^n \right | (z\in \mathbb C)$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $ a_n , b_n \in \mathbb C$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$ And there is $M>0$  such that $|a_n| \leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

Can we expect $\left | \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n b_n z^{n}  \right | \leq C \left | \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}  b_n z^n \right |  (z\in \mathbb C)$ ($C$ is some constant) ($z\in \mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1 = b_1 = 1$, $a_2 = b_2 = -1$, and let all the others be zero. Does there exist a constant $C$ for which $$|z + z^2| \le C |z - z^2|?$$

Hint: consider $z=1$.